# Why doesn't redis SADD work with an array as an input in node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using https://github.com/mranney/node_redis and trying to update a set with multiple values at once (on redis cli `"SADD myset val1 val2"` works fine).

The exact command I am using is:

```
var cmd_array = ['myset', 'val1', 'val2'];
client.sadd(cmd_array);
```

Based on their documentation this should of worked. Any idea why it doesn't?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works fine for me.
I can run the following script without any issue:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client_options = {
    parser: "hiredis"
};

var credis = redis.createClient( '/tmp/redis.sock', client_options );

function main()
{
   credis.flushall( function(err,res) {
      console.log( "hello" );
      x = [ "X", "A", "B", "C" ];
      credis.sadd(x);
      credis.sadd( "myset", x, function(err,res) {
         console.log("done");
         credis.end();
      });
   });
}

main();
```

It creates the two keys with the expected number of items:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1) "X"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2) "myset"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> smembers myset                                                                                                                                                                                                         
1) "X"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2) "A"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
3) "B"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
4) "C"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> smembers X                                                                                                                                                                                                             
1) "A"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2) "B"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
3) "C"
```

I would suggest you check the node_redis version.
The version I use is:

```
$ npm list
/home/dspezia/local/test_redis
├── hiredis@0.1.14 
└── redis@0.7.1
```

Comment: Thank you Didier for your reply. I am using version 0.7.2, by the way the exact error I am getting is "Error: Error: Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'sadd' command"

Comment: Just ran your code on the version I have got installed (0.7.2) and it throws the same error. questions is whether its a problem with my installation or the version.

Comment: I have upgraded to 0.7.2, and it still works fine for me. There is also node.js version itself to check. Do you use a dev branch (i.e. version > 0.6.16)?

Comment: One last bit, which version of redis server are you using? mine is Redis server version 2.2.12 (00000000:0)

Comment: Ah, that's probably it. Redis 2.2 is quite old now. Variadic parameters commands have been added with 2.4. Changelog here: https://github.com/antirez/redis/raw/2.4/00-RELEASENOTES

Comment: Yes that was the problem! upgraded the server and now it works (unbelievable waste of time, and all because of Ubuntu's default installation). Thank you very much for your help!